# Lie Group Isomorphisms

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups

I'm not sure of the difficulty of the question I'm about to ask. If it does not fit the criteria for this site then I apologize in advance, I'm rather new here.

So here it goes: Let $G$ be a Lie group and $Mod(G)$ be the mapping class group of the underlying manifold (by mapping class group I mean homeomorphisms from $G$ to itself up to isotopy). Denote the group of Lie-group isomorphisms as $Aut(G)$.

> In general, what is the relationship between $Mod(G)$ and $Aut(G)$?

It is clear that $Aut(G)$ injects the into $Homeo(G)$ (the set of all homeomorphisms of $G$ to itself) and we know $Mod(G)\cong Homeo(G)/homotopy$. However, there are certainly homeomorphisms in $Homeo(G)$ that do not preserve the group structure and moreover, an element of $Aut(G)$ must fix the identity. I guess a specific question of importance would be:

> When are two elements of $Aut(G)$ isotopic as homeomorphisms?

Also, would the case change if we were to work over a different category for $Mod(G)$ (i.e. PL, Diffeo, ect.)  I hope this all makes sense and meets the standards of the board.

Comment: Well for starters the automorphisms which are conjugation with $g\in G^0$ are isotopic to the identity, so there is a big chunk of $Aut(G)$ that vanishes in $Mod(G)$ (which I consider very bad notation btw)

Comment: So should we be looking at $Out(G)$ right off the bat? Also, I'm quite open to suggestions for notation, I'm just used to Farb's usage of $Mod(G)$. Is $\pi_0Homeo(G)$ better?

Comment: The truth might lie somewhere between Aut(G)/Inn^0(G) and Out(G). Consider the following: To each *diffeomorphism* $\alpha:G\to G$ we can associate the map $x\mapsto\det(D_x\alpha)$. An differentiable isotopy between $\alpha_1\to\alpha_2$ induces a homotopy between these maps. Since $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \simeq \{\pm 1\}$ we get a sign map $\pi_0(Diffeo(G)) \to Map(G\to\{\pm 1\})$. Are there conjugation automorphisms that have a nontrivial sign? I'm thinking of something like conjugation with a reflection on $O(n)$.

Comment: I think, you are confusing homotopy and isotopy, they are not the same, even for the 2-dimensional annulus! Next, restrict to connected groups, otherwise consider the case of finite groups. If you use isotopy, then, I think, for nilpotent connected Lie groups you get surjectivity of the map from out to mod, due to Farrell and Jones. Something similar might be true for compact simply connected groups.

Comment: I searched for Farrell/Jones and came across a conjecture. I am unfamiliar with the literature, I suppose you are referring to a particular solved case? And Johannes Hahn, after considering your question, it does not seem that conjugation automorphisms will have non-trivial sign but I'm still looking at examples.

Comment: I will find a reference when I have time, it is from 70s (maybe Farrell and Hsiang instead! I forgot who did what). In the meantime, for compact connected simple groups the result is also true, I will add a reference later on.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. References would be fantastic if it is not too much trouble at some point.